# Methods can't be applied to given types in Java

Tags: java, class, abstract-data-type

As part of an assignment that I have to do for my class, I have to create an ADT file that will accept user input for the numerators and denominators of fractions, compare the two, and determine whether the fractions are equal, then test it in a harness class.

One of the problems I am encountering is that I must have an `equals (Fraction f)` method that compares the two using the following formula:  `return getNum()*f.getDenom() == f.getNum()*getDenom();`.

Here is the code for my class so far:

```
public class Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    //default constructor
    public Fraction() {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 0;
    }

    public Fraction(int newNum, int newDenom) {
        numerator = newNum;
        denominator = newDenom;
    }

    //accessor
    public void setNewNum(int newNum) {
        numerator = newNum;
    }

    public void setNewDenom(int newDenom) {
        numerator = newDenom;
    }

    public int getNum(int newNum) {
        return newNum;
    }

    public int getDenom(int newDenom) {
        return newDenom;
    }

//Error here - "Methods getNum/getDenom in class Fraction cannot be applied to the given types:"
    public boolean equals(Fraction f) {
        return getNum()*f.getDenom() == f.getNum()*getDenom(); 
    }
}
```

Reading the error message in NetBeans says that the `"actual and formal argument lists differ in length."`  I'm working on trying to figure out what I did wrong but I was under the impression that `newNum` and `newDenom` already return values that are integers, since `newNum` and `newDenom` are set as equal to the numerator and denominator.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `getNum(int newNum)` != `getNum()`

Comment: A bit offtopic but do you think that it is safe to set `denominator` to 0 in the default constructor? I mean, we are talking about fractions. I would set it to 1

Comment: Pelocho - I always thought constructers were set to 0. Is that not correct?  I apologize, I'm still very new to anything beyond basic coding.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting that error is, your `getter` methods are defined to accept an `int` argument (e.g. `getNum(int newNum)`) whereas `equals` method does not pass any argument while calling `getNum`.

Ideally, the purpose of `getter` method is to return a value, so it does not need to accept any argument. Changing `getNum` and `getDenom` to below will fix the issue:

```
public int getNum() {
    return numerator;
}

public int getDenom() {
    return denominator;
}
```

[Here's](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm) the documentation and examples for `getter` and `setter` naming conventions.

Comment: Which comment ?

Comment: @Yahya Should have written an answer. Can't blame Darshan.

Answer (score 1):

`getNum(),getDenom()` /getters/ should be declared this way:

```
public int getNum() {//without any parameters
     return numerator; // not newNum
}

public int getDenom() {//without any parameters
   return denominator; //not newDenom
}
```